# how to set progress within progress-bar in android

Tags: android

this is my horizontal progress-bar->

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/point_one_progress"
        android:scaleY="0.80" />
```

this is my point_one_progress.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="12dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#cccccc"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="-1dp"

        >

        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="12dp"/>
                <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
            </shape>
        </scale>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

i am using horizontal progress-bar display progress based one point for more than 3 value progress coming perfect and within progress-bar but for 1,2,3 progress is coming outside the progress-bar  please suggest me how to fix it how to keep progress within progress-bar for 1,2,3 value .

you can see in below image for value 1->

[image]

for 10 value you can see screen

[image]

Comment: not able to understand your question properly. Can you elaborate it more?

Comment: @UmeshSonawane . see for point 1,2,3, you can see in image the progress color is coming out side the progress-bar while for more than 3 it come inside progress bar

Comment: @UmeshSonawane i have added one more screen for value 10 you can see difference  i want keep progress color within progress bar for 1,2,3

Comment: if it is not necessary to use rounded corner then remove radius, set it to 0dp and it will work perfectly.

Comment: @BhaskarMart, I am also facing the same problem right now, Did you find any solution about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's issue with drawable padding. You need to make it 0dp for all four sides.

Here is xml code.

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:progress="2"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/point_one_progress" />
```

Here is corrected drawable.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="12dp" />
            <solid android:color="#cccccc" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="12dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: can you check my problem again please i have updated my screen

Comment: @BhaskarMart I updated my answer with drawable. Let me know if you still face the issue.

Comment: @BhaskarMart can you please put your screen image after the change as I don't see issue in drawable. On the other note you need to remove "android:scaleY="0.80"  from xml.

Comment: not working after removing can u show me drawble xml and layout xml @Amit

Comment: @BhaskarMart Yes I have seen your screen shot. Drawable is same as what I posted. Here is the xml.

Comment: @BhaskarMart Hey I updated my answer for both xml and drawable as I can't put in comment. There are some change in drawable. Just I ran the code for value 1, 2 & 3. It shows correctly.

Comment: same issue  as i gave in charanrsk solution

Comment: in progress color you can see at end its not angled .

Comment: @BhaskarMart Interesting problem. I think this you can solve with 9 patch image. Here is one more thing you can try to see whether this works as per your expectation. Update your drawable item scale shape to have shape type as "oval".  <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
            <shape android:shape="oval">

Answer (score 0):

Its the issue with ur drawable. remove top , bottom fields from the item tag. Your drawable file should look like this.Also remove scaleY from the progress bar view

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>

            <corners android:radius="12dp"/>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/white"
                android:endColor=  "@color/white"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="12dp"/>

                <solid android:color="@color/primaryDarkColor"/>
            </shape>

        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: no its not working same issue dear for 1,2,3 value please check what issue am facing . @charanrsk

Comment: thanx its working let me check again will accept your answer

Comment: here one problem is coming that i want to set end also is angle  you can see screen in given image for value 10 but using your code end progress is coming rectangle

Comment: i didn't get you

Comment: you see displaying end progress view its angular but using your code its coming circular wait i ll show https://paste.pics/e4cc8e800a2e065cf88f67abd50230e7 check this end of progress inside progressbar @charanrsk

Comment: Please check https://pasteboard.co/HSgzmUk.png and my screen for value 10 for end of progress you will come to know what is problem is coming  i need end circular @charanrsk

Comment: I think that's not a thing which someone can notice. I will try to acheive that and post the answer. Till then , Can you accept my answer if it helped?

Comment: thanx but i have that is challenge for me in current implementation i am able to do what ever u gave solution but i need as  expected .

Comment: i am also facing same not able to find solution of this issu e

Comment: @charanrsk can you do one favour for background xml which you have given for value 1,2,3 can we make it  oval shap but it should fit inside